# I want to generate custom ID in table like R2023001 in Spring Boot Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

But my Question is that the id is generated to api or in database directly.

what is the better option, please share your answers and suggestions

My database is MySQL or MS SQL Server

Thanks in advance.

Generate custom Id and not interrupt at runtime when there is traffic on my app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how can we solve it easily but there is a workaround. You can create a custom id generator class. Don't forget, before set ID you have to check last value of id in database.

Here is example:

```
@Service
public class CustomIdGenerator {

    private static final String PREFIX = "R";
    private static AtomicInteger counter;

    private final YourRepository yourRepository;

    public CustomIdGenerator(YourRepository yourRepository) {
        this.yourRepository = yourRepository;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        int lastId = getLastIdFromDatabase();
        counter = new AtomicInteger(lastId);
    }

    public String generateId() {
        return PREFIX + counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    private int getLastIdFromDatabase() {
        String lastId = yourRepository.findLastId();
        if (lastId == null) {
            return 2023000;
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(lastId.substring(PREFIX.length()));
    }
}

    @Repository
    public interface YourRepository extends JpaRepository<YourEntity,  String> {
        @Query(value = "SELECT id FROM your_table ORDER BY id
         DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
        String findLastId();
    }
```

usage:

```
 public void saveYourEntity(YourEntity entity) {
        entity.setId(customIdGenerator.generateId());
        yourRepository.save(entity);
    }
```

Comment: I am not satisfied to your answer actually when I have numbers of user is login on my app and very one can insert data then last id how can define  so, how to manage it.